# How does latexmk find the file it should compile?

Tags: latexmk

Following up on [gedit [<-- missing link? -->] TexLive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12729/gedit-missing-link-texlive)

```
latexmk myfile.tex
```

delivers this answer:

```
Latexmk: Could not find file [myfile.tex]

Run number 1 of latex [myfile.tex]

This is pdfTexk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6) 

 %&-line parsing enabled.

entering extended mode

! I can't find file 'myfile.tex'

<*> myfile.tex   

Please type another input file name:
```

I renamed the file but still it could not be found.

does a `.tex` file have to be in a specific place in order to be found by `latexmk`?

Comment: Are you running this command in the same directory as `myfile.tex`?

Comment: @Matthew: Hmm, what to do? Post your comment as an answer or vote to close?

Comment: @Hendrik, @Alex: OK, I posted my comment as answer.  You all can still vote to close if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are running this command in the same directory as `myfile.tex`.