# About texhash and proper installation of TeXlive

Tags: installing, texlive, linux

So, I'm running linux Mint (but I guess the same applies to Ubuntu) and as is common knowledge, their `TeX` distribution tends to be slightly outdated. Now I can't have none of that and decide to install it with the install-tl from the TeXlive homepage. Somehow, I cannot install it as a normal user (this I find normal as it is installing in the root directory), so I proceed to install `TeXlive`

```
sudo perl ./install-tl
```

and add the paths to `.bashrc`. All is well and my `TeXlive` installation works. Except for the `texhash` option. Running it as a normal user is no problem, except that I installed `TeXlive` as root, and so running `texhash` as normal user doesn't do anything (`directory not writable. Skipping...`). No problem I think, I'll just do it as root. But somehow `texhash` isn't installed for root.

Now, `texhash` is somehow connected to updating the directory tree, but I don't really know what it does. I use it on my `~/texmf/` folder to add my packages to a global path (I think), but when looking at info for this question I see in a comment for [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30307/1614) question that this is apparently not needed, though I don't understand what I'm to do now.

So if I'm not adding new packages from CTAN or updating, I really don't need `texhash` and all is good?

To summarize: I'd like to know:

- Why should I need `texhash`?
- Can I avoid installing as root on linux Mint/ubuntu ([here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) they say you don't have to be root, that it's even discouraged)?
- Should I somehow install `texhash` for root?

I realize this might be a vague question at best, but I didn't find an answer I readily understood, so I'd appreciate any thought on this.

Comment: try adding `alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'` to your `.bashrc` (that's what helped here, on ubuntu)

Comment: `sudo mktexlsr`, as for all commands you're supposed to run with administrator privileges, after having done as henrique suggested.

Comment: Fantastic, the alias thing worked. What is the difference between running mktexlsr or texhash?

Comment: BTW [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/257666) where I learned that. (There's no rationale, it's just "an annoying function of sudo on ubuntu" :)

Comment: `mktexlsr` and `texhash` are the same thing, the later is a symlink to the former.

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html) answers most of your questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why should I need texhash?

TeX has lots of tiny files, .tfm files for instance.  So finding something involves a lot of disk activity.  Texhash looks once and remembers the locations of all the files in a simple single-file database, and then when TeX programs need to find those files the only reading is of that database.  Roughly, it remembers where your TeX-relevant files are.

The downside is that when you add or move files you need to run texhash.

> Can I avoid installing as root on linux Mint/ubuntu (here they say you don't have to be root, that it's even discouraged)?

I have installed as not-root on Ubuntu.  (At the moment, I use the debian packages though.)  If you have a one-person system probably root is the easiest.

> Should I somehow install texhash for root?

What does `whereis texhash` say?  (Mine says `/usr/bin/texhash`.)  What are the permissions?   For comparision, mine says this.

```
ftpmaint@millstone:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/texhash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 2011-05-25 08:01 /usr/bin/texhash -> mktexlsr
ftpmaint@millstone:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/mktexlsr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6885 2011-04-10 15:52 /usr/bin/mktexlsr
```

Comment: When I run `whereis texhash` I get `texhash:` That's not normal is it? But it seems to aknowledge it, as when I try `texhash --version` The terminal presents me with this wealth of information: `texhash $Id: mktexlsr 23151 2011-06-27 22:27:02Z karl $ kpathsea version 6.0.1 Copyright 2011 Karl Berry & Olaf Weber. License LGPLv2.1+: GNU Lesser GPL version 2.1 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.` Where is it?

Comment: It's probably on `/usr/bin/texlive/2011/bin/<e.g.i386-linux>/` try instead a `which texhash` (also check [this answer to "How can I call TexLive in Ubuntu?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6962/5872))

Comment: Mine is in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux` and the permissions are:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        8 2009-08-15 17:48 texhash -> mktexlsr

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     7479 2011-06-27 22:28 mktexlsr`

Answer (score 5):

> I use it (`texhash`) on my `~/texmf/` folder to add my packages to a global path (I think)

That's not what `texhash` does. It builds one index for each tree that is configured to use an index. The trees are independent, each with its own index, so files in your `~/texmf` are always personal. The index is useful, as Jim explained, to avoid searching for files on the disk, which would be pretty slow for big trees (last time I checked, the main tree was like 50.000 files in 5.000 directories). However, `~/texmf` usually does not contain that many files, so by default it is configured not to used an index (starting with TeX Live 2007).

Besides, even *if* `~/texmf` was using an index, you'd still be able to refresh it without being root by running `texhash ~/texmf` since the index is written at the root of the tree.

> Why should I need `texhash`?

So, short answer: if all you're doing is add files to `~/texmf` you simply do *not* need to run it.

> Can I avoid installing as root

Sure you can. Just choose a `TEXROOT` you have write permission to. This can be done in two ways: as root, grant write permission to you user on `/usr/local/texlive` and install there as a user. Or, install somewhere in your home, like `~/usr/texlive` or whatever you like.

Here on my Debian machine, I haven't installed TeX Live as root since a while, and never had the slightest problem with that. Besides, the page you're linking to belongs to TeX Live's official documentation, if it says you don't need to be root, you sure can believe that.

> Should I somehow install texhash for root?

There is no such thing as "installing". Just make sure `texhash` is in root's `PATH` *or* export your user's `PATH` as suggested in henrique's comment (probably the most convenient option) *or* call it with full path, like `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/texhash`.

Comment: With the former option, would I just make the directory `/usr/local/texlive` and grant permission as root before installing (the install-tl doesn't mind the directory being existent?)? Is the second option discouraged? I've seen something about the structure of linux directories being the way they are for a reason, and as user who doesn't know what he's doing, for the love of god don't mess with the structure. Could I just put the installation in my home directory and change the paths accordingly?