# Lost my ability to add .tex and .sty files when upgrading to texlive 2016 on ubuntu

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu, paths

Using the instructions from [How to install vanilla texlive on debian or ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) I upgraded from texlive 2014 to texlive 2016 on my second laptop. I did this because I am using some more recent packages and I don't think they will work with texlive 2014.

Now I do not seem to have the ability to add anything to my tex tree, which in my case is located at:

`/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist*`

So after adding to my tex tree, I did `sudo texhash`

`kpsewhich` picks up the 2016 packages fine, but I do not seem to be able to add anything.

I also tried adding a directory `~/texmf` putting the files in there and then doing `texhash ~/texmf` and still no joy.

`sudo texhash` produced:

```
texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R...
```

Does anybody know what can be done to fix the situation?  I would be mightily obliged to any kind person who might help me figure out a solution.  Thanks.

Adding:

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

and then running  `mktexlsr` as suggested in [About texhash and proper installation of TeXlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48292/about-texhash-and-proper-installation-of-texlive) had no effect (I logged out and logged in again)

Comment: There appears to be an answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48292/about-texhash-and-proper-installation-of-texlive to this question.

Comment: @JPi Sigh...did not work.  I had high hopes.

Comment: The second answer to the linked question is likely most pertinent. You do not need to run `texhash` on your personal tree (`~/texmf`). You should never manually add to `/usr/local/texlive/2016`. However, the main problem here is that you also have a distro-installed version of TL installed and you need to remove it.

Comment: That is, you did not follow the instructions sufficiently thoroughly. You need to remove all traces of `texlive` packages installed by your Linux distro's package manager and install a 'dummy' package to keep it happy.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your comment.  I don't know how to add files to my tree but manually at this point.  I guess there must be a tlmgr way of doing it?  I don't think that my 2014 installation is distro-installed as ubuntu is still stuck at 2012 at this point.  Should I remove the entire 2014 tex tree?  I was thinking that there was a missing step or 2 to upgrading.

Comment: You are definitely using a distro-installed version unless you have manually altered the configuration of upstream's TeX Live to use similar paths. TL does not use the paths listed in your question by default. It is not a question of manual or not. It is a question of which tree. You shouldn't install manually (i.e. yourself) into the main `texmf` tree. You should use your personal or local tree. But all of this is irrelevant given that you are using Ubuntu's packaged binaries.

Comment: I guess I'll just nuke both texlive installations and try it again.

Comment: Nuking stuff under `/usr/local/texlive` will have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks @cfr it turns out I have ubuntu's texlive 2013 was  installed alongside of my 2014 installation and my 2016 installation.  And `sudo apt-get remove texlive` removed the 2013 version.  Now it works.  If you care to put it up as the answer I'll pick it. And thanks for being patient. Seems no dummy package was needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by OP himself (see comments).

Comment: You need a dummy package to stop your package manager reinstalling it if you decide to install something with `texlive` as a dependency. It is not at all wise to skip this step.

Comment: Like `gummi` which I had to remove alongside of texlive 2013.  Ok.  Thanks.